# Dynamically Swap Components at Mount Results in Uncaught Error

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React app that at the either needs to load a View Only Form Component or a Edit Component.  In order to solve this I have the following code...

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './app.js';

ReactDOM.render((
<BrowserRouter>
<App /> 
</BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('main')
);
```

App.Js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import  '../scss/custom.scss';
import Patient from './components/patient.js';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Patient />
    );
  }
};
```

Patient.js: PATIENT contains Overview and COMPPROPS contains compState being passed to OverviewWrapper

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
...
import OverviewWrapper from '../components/patientoverviewwrapper.js';

export default class Patient extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);

    this.state = {
      PATIENT: [],
      COMPPROPS: [],
    };
   }

componentDidMount() {   

//this function gets the data that will load in either the View or Edit Form
getPatient().then((result) => {
    this.setState({PATIENT: result});
});
//this function gets the data to determine if either the edit or view form should load
loadOverviewEditPane(activity); 
}
render() {
  return (
  ...
 <Box colorIndex='light-2'  direction='row' flex={false}>
                             return (
                               <OverviewWrapper overview={this.state.overview} state={this.state.compState} />
                             );
                      </Box>
```

OverviewWrapper.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import autoBind from 'react-autobind';
import OverviewPane from '../components/patientoverview.js';
import OverviewEditPane from '../components/patientoverviewedit.js';

export default class OverviewWrapper extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);
  }

render() {
    const ov = this.props.overview
    const type = this.props.compState


    let OverviewWrapper = null
    switch (type) {
        case "Edit" : OverviewWrapper = <OverviewEditPane overview={ov} />
        break
        default: OverviewWrapper = <OverviewPane overview={ov} />
        break
    }

    return (
        React.createElement(OverviewWrapper, this.props, null)
    )
}
}
```

When I run the application I get the following error in the console.

**Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `OverviewWrapper`.**

My first time doing this and it appears that I should be using a Wrapping design which is what I'm employing here but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe change your approach a little bit and set component type first and later set its props:

```
render() {
  const ov = this.props.overview
  const type = this.props.compState

  let OverviewWrapper = null
  switch (type) {
    case "Edit":
      OverviewWrapper = OverviewEditPane
      break
    default:
      OverviewWrapper = OverviewPane
      break
  }

  return <OverviewWrapper {...this.props} overview={ov} />
}
```

Working sample:

```js
const OverviewEditPane = ({ overview }) =>
  <div>
    OverviewEditPane: {overview.name}
  </div>

const OverviewPane = ({ overview }) =>
  <div>
    OverviewPane: {overview.name}
  </div>

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const Component = this.props.type === 0 ? OverviewEditPane: OverviewPane
    return (
      <div>
        <Component {...this.props} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const overview = { name: 'test' }

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <App type={0} overview={overview} />
    <App type={1} overview={overview} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Still getting an error but at least moved past the original issue.  Really appreciate the help.